# Can I take my prequalification letter anywhere in the state?

Tags: united-states, mortgage-qualification, credit-unions

My family and I are about to apply for a pre-qualification letter with our credit union, but we honestly have not seen any houses in the city we live in that we like.

Are we constrained, once we get a pre-qualification letter with our credit union to have to only shop in the city we currently live in? Could we take that pre-qual anywhere in the state we choose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask the credit union where they can approve mortgages. Mine in the DC area can approve a loan anywhere in DC, MD and VA. They don't have the ability to make a loan to properties outside of those states.

I would be surprised if it was only in a city, or a handful of counties, but they will  know the answer to this question.